# Open notepad, then detect filepath for any output save file.

Tags: python-3.x, executable, filepath

I need to open notepad from python3 then obtain the file path to any file written by the program. Here is what I've tried.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import subprocess as sp

''
cmd = r'C:\path_to_notepad.exe'
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, 
universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('\0\1\1')

print("stdout: %r\nstderr: %r" % (stdout, stderr))
if p.returncode !=0:
  raise sp.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd, output = 
(stdout, stderr)
)
```

I'm not sure if this is correct. It opens fine but I can't get any output. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: notepad is not going to be writing to stdout. it's writing to a file. There is probably a better way to do this, but look at instrumenting the NtCreateFile syscall with something like Intel's Pin.

Comment: How can I find said file?

Comment: So we hook it? I'm looking for the documentation, I'm not familiar with this. Can you provide a link to your favorite documentation on this?

Comment: You write a pintool that hooks the NtCreateFile syscall for any binary it's run with. Then you do something like "pin mypintool notepad.exe" and you will get a callback every time NtCreateFile is called. So you run pin instead of notepad directly. You can find Windows syscall numbers [here (x64)](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/) and [here (x86)](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/32/)

Comment: You are awesome. I'm really slow at this. I'll have a look. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Look at the strace example in the Pin package. If I recall correctly it handles syscalls.

Comment: Could you direct me, one more time to  documentation that might have examples of such implementations. My apologies.

Comment: This is the syscall example: https://github.com/jingpu/pintools/blob/master/source/tools/ManualExamples/strace.cpp

Comment: Slow may have been an understatement. I do not understand what they are doing here. I have a tutor that may be able to explain it to me tomorrow, but for now I'm lost. I'd really like to learn this myself, but if you were kind enough to outline a sample code, could you also explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: It's not easy for a beginner to handle. Is this for hw? They're probably not expecting you to use something like Pin in that case. Pin will call your "pintool" code, which will then callback into Pin and tell it what hooks to set up. Pin will then run the executable as a debugger would and call your hooks at the right times. In your hooks you can view arguments, return values, etc... Syscalls are more accurate than hooking function calls for getting return values which is why I said to hook it there.

Comment: I am terrible at diagramming, but this is sort of what happens: https://imgur.com/a/V38pV. You write the pintool.

Comment: No not homework. I have a decent sized project I was working on. Most of it was text editing, some simple base64 encryption and decrypt, and now a way to automate it all. Seems like this has been the most difficult part. I hired the tutor in hopes I could both finish the project and have functional knowledge. There's also about four more tasks needed he will be assisting with. It nice to have someone to work with, paid or not.

Comment: Cool, sounds good. The pin manual is quite nice and helped me quite a bit: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/

Comment: This is more like it. There is a robust explanation and lots of examples. Thank you. I may have more questions but for now I think I will have my hands full for awhile. I meant to add that this project was a community project. I intend on releasing it for free to others. Notepad is not the actual object of my attention. At the moment it's craftware which is for 3d printing. But it's output is basically a text file. A single line in it is encrypted but very easy to decrypt. There's a perl program on hackaday that does non planar sinoidal layering which is really cool. I plan on adding it later.

Comment: I suppose this will be continued for an answer. I can't upvoted a comment..upvoted the question I've never had an upvoted lol. It's a good question :)

Comment: Lol ok I'll add an answer. I hadn't done so because I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do what you're asking for.

Comment: So what I've heard back is he is unfamiliar with this. It will take some time for him to work it out. Should this be complicated for even an experienced coder? I was hoping him and me would write a working example tomorrow. I may need to pay him to research? I really only wanted one hour a week. Darn.

Comment: It can be. All depends on the coder's area of expertise. I'm not surprised he hasn't heard of it. I hadn't until recently actually. And it's in C++, which is not easy if you don't know it.

Comment: Oh well I was following a bit of it but it kept losing me. I  can't possibly start learning a new language at the moment so I'm just gonna ask you. Can you outline a working sketch that would open and capture a save file. I understand if you have better things to do. Thanks in advance either way.

Comment: I can't promise anything, but I had intended to write a pintool for NtCreateFile and NtWriteFile tomorrow for my own purposes. I can link you the source code if I do end up writing it.

Comment: I can't get anything to compile with the latest version of pin and pin 2.14 seems really unstable, so you will probably have to take a different route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intel's Pin library and hook the NtCreateFile syscall. You can find the syscall numbers [here (x64)](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/) and [here (x86)](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/32/).

Basically you write a pintool to register callbacks at the instruction level, basic block level, function level, etc... Then you run Pin, passing in your pintool and the program you want to instrument (in this case notepad).

If you hook the NtCreateFile syscall, you will be able to view the parameters and return value for that syscall every time notepad calls it. You can find an example on this in the strace example in the Pin package.

You might be able to find python bindings for Pin as well. If not, you'll have to find another way to communicate back to python.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to up-vote. I'm too new. My apologies.

Comment: @Jasong Yeah I know. It's all good. You don't have enough rep. All you can do is accept the answer if you think it answers the question.